# how to modify kernel to activate SPI-devices on 12.04 Pandaboard?

Tags: kernel

There are many examples online for modifying and building kernel, but non of them would realy work! I want to activate SPI-Devices to work with. It needs also GPIO-Interrupt
for triggering SPI-Read-routine. This is no problem on RaspberryPi, I allready done but the throughput is limited. There for I'm trying to use Pandaboard for this task.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a patch on the kernel to use it.

You may use this link to modify the files,
http://www.omappedia.com/wiki/PandaBoard_SPI

There are multiple ways to interface the SPI devices with Pandaboard, Mostly you will be using the SPI available on J3 connector.

Some parts from the link mentioned above:

> You do not need to write any kernel code and study the kernel API for
> SPI. The kernel already contains several sort of device drivers.
>
> Pandaboard's SPI masters are fully supported by the Linux kernel's
> mcspi driver. That being said, one will need to make only some minor
> modifications to the PandaBoard's board file
> (arch/arm/mach-omap2/board-omap4panda.c) in order to use them.

Long back I had a chance to work with RPi SPI, and as you said, there is no pain in using the SPI on RPi. On Panda, we need to perform some hacks.